# Same validator for different fields

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

So this is the situation:

I have two serializer classes, one inheriting from another.

```
class FatherSerializer(...):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'brother')

    name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    brother = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if Person.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Such email already exists')
        return value

    def validate_brother(self, value):
        if not Person.objects.filter(name=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Such person doesnt exist')
        return Person.objects.get(name=value)

class ChildSerializer(FatherSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'sister')

    sister = serializers.CharField()
```

I want to use the same validator for "sister" as it is used for "brother". It works for the email, since the name of the field is the same. But is there a way of making the same serializer to work for 2 different fields?

I tried a custom validator, by implementing it outside of both classes and using it in `validators` parameter of the Field. But it is not working properly, because I want the returned value to be a Person object, but all I get is the original input value (so, "name").

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your own `SiblingField` with your custom validation and then use it both on your `FatherSerializer` for `brother` and on your `ChildSerializer` for `sister`.

```
class SiblingField(serializers.CharField):
    <add your custom validation methods here>

class FatherSerializer(...):
    brother = SiblingField()

class ChildSerializer(FatherSerializer):
    sister = SiblingField()
```

Comment: yeah, this makes sense. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FatherSerializer there for 'sister' field

```
sister = FatherSerializer()
```

Comment: So you're suggesting for `sister` instead of being a `CharField` be an object of `FatherSerializer` class? This makes for `sister` to be expecting a dictionary complying with `FatherSerializer` needs.. So not working just like this.